# Build Flutter app in release mode for iOS

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, build, release

I have Android Studio with Flutter plugin installed.
Flutter SDK is also installed on my Mac through Android Studio and I know path to it.

I want to run my app in release mode on real iOS device. Not only to hide "slow mode" banner that can be done using this code as I know

```
new MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  ...
```

but also to check how my app works.

I found this instructions https://flutter.io/ios-release/ but still can't build app in release mode.

Each time I try to run flutter command in terminal, I got:

> flutter: command not found

I think that it is because I had installed Flutter SDK from Android Studio and I should update some pathes.
So what are my steps to build flutter app in release mode using Xcode?

Comment: You need to add flutter/bin to your path

Comment: so I open my terminal, where should I go with cd command? and what should I do next?

Comment: Follow the instructions [here](https://flutter.io/setup-macos/)

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't helping.

Comment: It should. There's a problem with your install.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Building steps**

If you have problems using flutter command in terminal because it is not found - read *Configuring steps* below.

**Step 1**

Open terminal, run command

```
cd /Users/John/myFlutterApp/
```

Run

```
flutter build ios
```

Open Xcode and run .xcworkspace file in iOS folder. It should now work smoothly and Slow mode banner should be gone.

**Configuring steps**

**Step 1**

Locate folder where flutter is installed on your mac. If it was installed using Android Studio. Just open Android Studio create new flutter project and you will see **Flutter SDK path**.
For example let it be /Users/John/flutter/

**Step 2**

open terminal on your Mac and run

```
cd /Users/John/
```

As you can see we are now one level up from SDK path

**Step 3**

run

```
export PATH=`pwd`/flutter/bin:$PATH
```

If you now run **flutter** in terminal you should see list of available params. So you can run

```
flutter doctor
```

To check is everything is fine with installation.
Now flutter command only works for this terminal session. And if you close it and later open it again and run fuller command - you will get error that this command is unknown. So you want to save flutter command to be available even after terminal was closed.

**Step 4**

run

```
open ~/.bash_profile
```

you will see text editor where you need to paste

```
export PATH=/Users/John/flutter/bin:$PATH
```

save file. If you close terminal now and open it again - you should be able to run flutter command.

Comment: Helpful answer! I didn't know that you have to run  `flutter build ios` from command line to build in release mode.

Comment: otherwise app will run much slower

Comment: To publish the app on App Store specify development team  or enable automatic sign-in in Xcode , then run `flutter build ios --release` and it will make release build.

Answer (score 71):

Even after running `flutter build ios`, Xcode always ran the Debug version (slow mode).

To solve this, I had to change the **Build Configuration** of the **Run** schema:

1. Click on **Runner**, and **Edit scheme**

[image]

2. Select **Release** for the Build Configuration of the **Run** schema

[image]

Hoping this is helpful.

Comment: Very useful - this is the first time I am seeing this.  So far for all the docs and reading I have been looking at on running a Flutter iOS build, I have not run across this important detail until your post.  Big Thanks

Comment: By default `flutter build ios` use `--debug` mode. In order to make it run in release, you need to add `--release` explicitly. I.e `flutter build ios --release`

Comment: No, `flutter build ios` uses `--release` mode by default.

Comment: Very helpful, didn't see this either!! They should put it in the release docs, given that `flutter build iOS` creates a release build by default and Xcode is not very revealing on this, it's easy to get wrong on this one.

Comment: Lately my laptop will not recognise that my iOS devices are connected except via Xcode - so I have to build/run via Xcode - so happy to find that this flag can be set this way - thank you !   Also - while it is right there in the answer, I somehow missed the "Set to *Run* schema" on my first try of this - make sure you do that step ! :)

Comment: Thankyou this helped me. (I just edited schema, and changed build mode to release in XCode)

Answer (score 33):

You can **Run** your application in **[Release Mode](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios)** easily in your terminal using :

```
flutter run --release
```

And it will switch to **Release Mode** .

But if you don't want to run your app , just want to build your apk or ipa  ,
**Use :**

```
 flutter build --release
```

> You can specify to build for ios by using `flutter build ios`

Comment: but if you disable the developer mode from your iPhone/ iPad application will not run.

Answer (score 23):

Follow these 3 steps:

1. Open your Flutter project in Xcode.
2. Top Bar Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme
3. Build Configuration - Select Release

*Note: Release type flutter app is valid for 7 days on iOS devices.*

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 22):

You could do it from Android Studio directly as well.

`>` **Run**
`>` **Flutter Run 'main.dart' in Release Mode**

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I just wanted to build the ios .ipa file for the testing purpose without any hustle, follow are the step I took, and hopefully, they will be helpful.

1. In the terminal run this command.

   flutter build ios --release --no-codesign
2. After that go to the folder where the output is stored.

> build/ios/iphoneos

3. After that you will have to create a new directory/folder in the iphoneos folder called "Payload".
4. After that move the output file "Runner.app" (name can be different) to the "Payload" folder.
5. Then compress the "Payload" folder and rename to "YouAppName.ipa".
   (make sure to change the extension)

And it's done.

> The solution will help you get .ipa file without signing.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to use only Android Studio to deploy your app in release mode, you can also add the --release flag to your Run/Debug configuration manually.

[image]