# Why my iOS app's size created with Flutter is 475MB?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, size

I created my first app. Not so big, news app. My dependencies:

```
  provider: ^4.3.2+2
  url_launcher: ^5.5.2
  share: ^0.6.5+4
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.10
  flutter_html: ^1.0.2
  cached_network_image: ^2.3.3
  flutter_spinkit: "^4.1.2"
  pull_to_refresh: ^1.6.3
  sqflite: ^1.3.2+1
  path_provider: ^1.6.24
  connectivity: ^2.0.2
  yoyo_player: 
  shimmer: ^1.1.2
  firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3
  dio_http_cache: ^0.2.11
  dio: ^3.0.10
  hive: ^1.4.4+1
  hive_flutter: ^0.3.1
  scrollable_positioned_list: ^0.1.8
```

I will list app sizes in different cases:
`flutter build apk` => size around 25MB.
`flutter build apk --split-per-abi` => size around 10MB.
`flutter build ios` => size of Runner.app is 475MB (I'm not joking).
Ok I can compress it => size 203MB - This is

Ok, flutter I'll create a blank app
`flutter build ios` => size of Runner.app is 65MB and after compress 23 (this seems affordable).

Comment: Maybe this can help you understand why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61975751

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I Archived app with XCode and deployed to the App Store app size was only 45MB (shown on Console) and after download to actual device size was only 29 MB.

From 475 to 29MB. That was amazing!

I think this can be helpful to someone else, so don't worry about size...

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will you

`flutter clean`

`flutter build ios --analyze-size`

Comment: I tried to clean before. Same size. Actually, my question is WHY?