# Flutter: Display log in release mode in iOS

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

I'm trying to display logs in **release mode** in iOS to test my in App Purchases...

I tried **print()** & **log()** but nothing works

*Fun fact, it works in Android.*

Do you know how to do that?

Thank you

Comment: [logger package](https://pub.dev/packages/logger) which I am also personally using logs in release mode but I would not recommend to debug in release mode because DevTools work unreliably :)

Comment: @NiklasvonHaxthausen logger package does not print any logs in release on ios

Answer (score 10):

I had the exact same problem! I was also testing in-app purchases on an iOS physical device and could not see the logs in Android Studio. I have tried the `print()` method, the flutter default logger, and also [the logger package](https://pub.dev/packages/logger).

You have to switch to Xcode and do the following steps:

1. Open Xcode
2. In the menu bar, go to `Product` > `Scheme` > `Edit Scheme...`

[image]

3. Make sure `Run` is selected on the left sidebar
4. In `Build Configuration`, change from `Debug` to `Release`

[image]

5. Compile your app in Xcode by pressing the "Play"/Run button and it should work

**Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61975751/5734066**