# Flutter: Build and deploy in release Mode on iOS 14+. How long usable?

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter

If I build and deploy my flutter app in release mode through "Edit scheme" => Release mode (description here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61975751/11543864):
How long can I use this app on my iPhone without reinstalling the app?

Answer (score 0):

I tested it and the result is following:
The app is in release mode for 7 days = 168h available.
After that you have to reinstall the app